# Couchbase - Slow Retrieval

Tags: couchbase

I am a developer on a Couchbase/AngularJS/Express.js/Node.JS application.  The application current state is the beginning of User Testing.  As the users are accessing the new application, a user wants to have a retrieve from Couchbase reviewed for efficiency.  The user feels that search is taking too long to return from Couchbase.  As an experienced SQL programmer and learning N1QL, my SQL experience is telling me the request is not feasible.

The process involves the following:

- 1700 to 1800 JSON Documents
- Expected return is either zero or some documents
- All documents is impossible (will explain shortly).
- The data must travel across the Atlantic because the data and application will reside on a machine within England.

The user will enter at a minimum three character to search for a name and expect a list of name returned containing the characters entered.  Please remember, the more characters entered by the user results in a much more refined search.  The user issue is that it is taking a couple of seconds to return.

The N1QL statement looks as follows:

```
SELECT id,
       name,
       abbr,
       meta(bucket).id meta_id
 FROM bucket
WHERE type = 'store'
  and Upper(name) like Upper('%passedinname%’)
order by name
```

If the user enters, ‘ABC’, the N1QL statement will return all JSON document information where the store JSON document contains ‘ABC’ in the name.  For example, if I had stores named:

1. ABC Market
2. Mary’s AbC Deli

Both documents would return.  As you may notice, I have to keep the search case insensitive.  This is per the user request.

I looked over the options within Couchbase.  I believe there is no viable means to increase the retrieval speed.  I looked into Couchbase View.  I do not see how I can apply my N1QL statement against it.  The couch.model.js script only allows for retrieval from the view.  It does not allow for the entrance of search criteria that not key values.

I looked into Couchbase Index.  I do not see how I can apply my N1QL statement against it either.  The N1QL statement will still need to search each store JSON document for the ‘passedinname’.

I even looked into Couchbase Full Text Search.  I cannot use this option.  The department has set up a policy to prevent it.

If you have a possible solution, please feel free to make a suggestion.  I appreciate all suggestion gratefully.

TIA
Anthony

Answer (score 0):

You are in luck. Unlike SQL, N1QL handles this with indexed speedup. There are two approaches: one for arbitrary substrings, including partial words, and another for whole words and / or tokens.

For partial words, see the SUFFIXES() function. It is more appropriate for shorter fields (e.g. tags, name, title) than longer fields (e.g. long description).

For whole words, see TOKENS() and SPLIT().

Both approaches are described in these articles.

https://dzone.com/articles/a-couchbase-index-technique-for-like-predicates-wi

https://dzone.com/articles/split-and-conquer-efficient-string-search-with-n1q

https://dzone.com/articles/more-than-like-efficient-json-search-with-couchbas

Comment: Thank you for the response.  It appears that I may be able to use SUFFIXES function.  I will need to find out the expected upgrade schedule.  Since the version currently does not contain the SUFFIXES function.